# Uri Object is not initializing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I must be making mistake somewhere. See the image. My code is like as follows.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:59180/Api/");
```

If I could evaluate `new Uri("http://localhost:59180/Api/");` it shows correct result. But when it is set to the variable "uri" of "Uri" type it just cannot assign values properly and throwing System.NullReference exception.

I am using .Net Framework 4.5. The same code is working properly in my other project.

[image]

Comment: Please post you code here so we can see it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.